# Chromecast self-signed SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, google-cast, chromecast

I've some problems with chromecast and self signed ssl certificate. I tried to implement my own receiver and registered my URL on Google Cast Developer Console.
Chromecast sender application trys to start and then i get some errors.

Does anyone knows if chromecast works with self signed certificates?

Answer (score 2):

It won't work with self-signed certs. For development, you can consider using App Engine or Google Drive since both have valid certs.
Update: Google Drive is no longer an option.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to worry about certs if you're app is ready to publish. During development you can work over HTTP. From https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration

*"Enter a URL that the Google Cast device should request when loading your receiver app. During development the URL can use HTTP but when the app is published it has to use HTTPS. The URL may be for an HTML page or other file type accessible from a web browser. It's okay for your receiver to be on an internal (NAT-registered) IP address, but not on localhost, as it is rarely a top level domain. Although the receiver app must be served over SSL (HTTPS) when published, the content loaded on the receiver app may be served over HTTP.
Although the receiver app must be served over SSL (HTTPS), the content loaded on the receiver app may be served over HTTP."*